# $f$ is continuous , $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt$?

Tags: real-analysis

> $f(x)$ is continuous function, then
> $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt = xf(x^2).$$

my solution is

> let  $u= x^2-t^2$, then we have
> $$\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2} f(u)du,$$ so
> $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{x^2} f(u)du = xf(x^2).$

I don't know if my solution is correct?  the main problem is that the step "$u = x^2 - t^2$" is reasonable?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You applied the substitution rule correctly. What exactly are your doubts about the solution?

Comment: @MartinR the integral is like $\int_0^x g(x,y)dy$, the substitution rule that i have learned is only for one variable. so my doubts it is the rule also well for two variables?

Comment: You apply the substution rule to the integral $\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt$ for a fixed value of $x$. That is an integral with respect to the single variable $t$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it correct. For fixed $x$ you apply the substitution rule to an integral with respect to the single variable $t$:
$$
\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{x^2} f(u)du \, ,
$$
Then, when differentiating this with respect to $x$, you apply the chain rule. With $F(x) = \int_0^{x} f(u)du $:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2)dt = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac 12 F(x^2) \right) = \frac 12 F'(x^2) 2x = x f(x^2) \, .
$$